# Como refatorar o meu método eliminando o setTimeOut que esta controlando o ciclo de vida?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Um perfil esta vindo de um componente pai:

```
<app-telefone-form [perfil]="perfil"></app-telefone-form>
```

Mas, quando ele chega no componente filho, é preciso retardar a consulta em 53ms. Veja:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.initTelefoneForm();
    this.initRedeSocialForm();
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (this.perfil) {
        this.findAllTelefonesByPessoa();
      }
    }, 54);
  }
```

Isso para mim é uma gambiarra, o uso do setTimeOut para controlar o ciclo de vida, logo, gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma de tratar isso refatorando para algo mais elegante, já que o perfil só propaga 53ms depois.

Comment: _"é preciso retardar a consulta"_ - porquê? como chegaste a essa conclusão?

Comment: Não sei ainda o motivo... mas o tempo de propagação demora 54ms para que a instância do objeto chegue ao destino.

Answer (score 1):

Para usar os dados recebidos pelo componente deve esperar até o evento `afterViewInit`, só partir dele os dados estarão setados na sua classe, no `ngOnInit` ainda não estará disponível porque vem antes

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.initTelefoneForm();
  this.initRedeSocialForm();
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  if (this.perfil) {
    this.findAllTelefonesByPessoa();
  }
}
```

Comment: Viva, no componente precisa de adicionar "implements AfterViewInit" e a sua utilização é ngAfterViewInit() { }. E efectivamente, este é executado após o componente estar carregado, já estão disponíveis os elementos na DOM. Tem neste post mais detalhes, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46162234/what-is-the-difference-between-ngafterviewinit-and-ngafterviewchecked.

Comment: Verdade faltou prefixar com o `ng`. Mas **não precisa** implementar a interface `AfterViewInit`

Comment: Sim. O uso das interfaces em angular do ciclo de vida é opcional. Eles apenas o ajudam como developer. Tecnicamente, o TypeScript é convertido para JavaScript, com o processo de transpile, que não possui interfaces. Basta chamar os métodos do JavaScript Lifecycle, se existirem. Essa é a razão pela qual não faz diferença se você usa as interfaces ou não.

Comment: No entanto, você deve usar as interfaces por vários motivos:
i) É mais claro quais eventos do Ciclo de Vida são realmente usados. Nas grandes classes com muitos métodos, você perde rapidamente a visão geral. O uso das interfaces permite determinar rapidamente todos os métodos de “life cicle” usados em um único local - no início da classe no TypeScript.
ii) O compilador TypeScript avisa se você não implementar os métodos de “life cicle” corretamente, por exemplo, se você esqueceu de implementar o método, digitou incorretamente o nome do método ou o método foi removido acidentalmente.

Comment: Antes de você comenta isso, comecei a fazer um a pergunta sobre isso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/429433/qual-a-vantagem-de-implementar-as-interfaces-dos-eventos-do-ciclo-de-vida-do-ang

Comment: Tens aí a resposta...

Comment: Eu tentei fazer isso antes, mas é que ainda neste ponto, o perfil ainda se encontra no estado de undefined.

Comment: Você passa esse objeto assincronamente (por exemplo, carrega de uma API no componente pai e então envia para o filho)?

Answer (score 0):

Se você precisa que o o método `findAllTelefonesByPessoa` seja invocado após a propriedade perfil ter algum valor, você pode usar um `setter` desta propriedade recebida por `@Input` e invocar o método dentro do `setter`.
Se você precisou atrasar a chamada deste método para esperar alguma outra propriedade, verifique se os outros métodos `initTelefoneForm` e `initRedeSocialForm` realizam alguma ação assíncrona.

```
export class TelefoneFormComponent implements OnInit {

  private _perfil: any; // declare o tipo correto

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initTelefoneForm();
    this.initRedeSocialForm();
  }

  @Input()
  set perfil(value: any) {
    this._perfil = value;
    this.findAllTelefonesByPessoa();
  }
}
```