# Qual a vantagem de implementar as interfaces dos eventos do ciclo de vida do Angular?

Tags: angular

O Angular possui uma interface pra cada evento do seu ciclo de vida, por exemplo, `OnInit` para o método `ngOnInit`

Já que não é necessário implementar tais interfaces para que se possa usufruir dos eventos, qual a vantagem de implementar as interfaces dos eventos do ciclo de vida do Angular nos componentes que utilizam esses eventos?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O uso das interfaces em angular do ciclo de vida é opcional. Eles apenas o ajudam como developer. Tecnicamente, o TypeScript é convertido para JavaScript, com o processo de transpile, que não possui interfaces. Basta chamar os métodos do JavaScript Lifecycle, se existirem. Essa é a razão pela qual não faz diferença se você usa as interfaces ou não.
No entanto, você deve usar as interfaces por vários motivos:

- É mais claro quais eventos do “life cicle” são realmente usados. Nas
  grandes classes com muitos métodos, você perde rapidamente a visão
  geral. O uso das interfaces permite determinar rapidamente todos os
  métodos de “life cicle” usados em um único local - no início da
  classe no TypeScript.
- O compilador TypeScript avisa se você não implementar os métodos de
  “life cicle” corretamente, por exemplo, se você esqueceu de
  implementar o método, digitou incorretamente o nome do método ou o
  método foi removido acidentalmente.